# Unity: Rotate towards mouse in 3D topdown view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, mouse

So I am trying to create a kind of turrent like a tank. The upper section needs to look at my mouse. I have tried

```
GetComponent().ScreenToWorldPoint(Argument);
```

many times togheter with

Input.mousePosistion();

But I couldn't figure this out really. I am programing this in C# if any one could help or provide a simple script that works in a 3D setting that would be great!

My code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Laser : MonoBehaviour {
    public float Speed;
    public AudioClip LaserSFX;
    private Transform Player;
    public Vector3 mousePos;
    public Camera Cam;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GameObject player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        Player = player.transform;
        if(!GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying)
        GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayOneShot (LaserSFX);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //Code to look at mouse or rotate
        //Code to move towards it

        float dist = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, transform.position);
        if (dist >= 500) 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

With kind regards,

Misterk99

Comment: Can you please just clarify the question? your doubt is how to get the coords of the mouse, or the rotation algorithm?

Comment: All I am trying to do is to get the cords of the mouse,
then rotate the object towards it.

Since my camera is rotated to a topdown view the mouse.y axis is the z axis in the world space.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the mouse position to the view position, this means the ScreenToWorldPoint should be provided to you by the camera you are using at that time, and since you already have the camera as cam:

```
         Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
         pos = Cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
```

with that now you have to face the position, and since you are using topdown 3D i supose the camera is facing the -y position. if so, don't forget to set the y you want:

```
pos.y = (your value here, depending to the position you are giving to your objects);
Vectgor3 dir = this.position - pos;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up);
```

Comment: Alright almost there,
http://imgur.com/BSP90gg
Is how the view looks the space ship is at XYZ 0,0,0
So the mouse x should be converted to the world z axis right?

Comment: when you use the Cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos), you already have that conversion taken care of, you get the coords where the camera sees the mouse

Comment: Now I have this:
`Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
  pos = Cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);

  pos.y = 0;
  Vector3 dir = transform.position - pos;
  float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
  transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up);`

And for some reason it isn't doing anything

Comment: try to do replate the angle code you have with float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.z, dir.x); i forgot to replace the y with the z since we are dealing with the xz plane and not the xy. Sorry for that xD

Comment: This is killing me xD It rotates to a certain point when I hti play after that nothing:
[Click for code](http://pastebin.com/XXccht6e)
Why is this so hard to do?

Comment: in your code, swap this

float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.x,dir.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

for this

float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.z,dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

atan receives the y as a first argument, and since you have the z instead of y, this should be one of the reasons

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution while trying to find one for myself. The answer @Spike gave led me on the right track. However, I used the mouse's viewpoint position and converted the objects position to the viewport position. Here is the code in Javascript (what I am using) which should be easy enough to convert to C#.

My camera is facing the -Y direction, FYI.

```
﻿#pragma strict

var cam: Camera;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {

    var mousePos: Vector3 = Input.mousePosition;
    var playerPos: Vector3 = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

    var dir: Vector3 = mousePos - playerPos;

    var angle: float = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-angle, Vector3.up);
}
```

Comment: Okay... so I know this is a year old, but what if my camera isn't facing the -Y direction? I can't figure out how your code determines that.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I just subtracted 90 from the angle. I also inverted the Vector3 to Vector3.down. If you don't do this, simply add 90 to the angle. My camera is facing the +Z axis :
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle + -90, Vector3.down);